# Merge two datasets per group for non existing values

Tags: r, merge, group-by

I have built a bipartie graph to identify similar users based on their skills and would like to recommend specific training for each of them.

My first dataset (let's called it **Dataset A**) looks like this:

```
UserID    Trainings
1         Speaking
1         Writing
1         Dancing
2         Writing
2         Dancing
2         Singing
2         Running
3         Speaking
3         Running
```

And my **Dataset B** that contains the list of all similar users:

```
UserID      Similar_Users
1           2
1           5
1           6
2           4
```

What I would like is to have a dataset with all the missing trainings per user based on the Trainings of their similar users.
In my example, it would look like:

```
UserID     Recommended_Trainings
1          Singing     
1          Running
```

Singing and Running because based on my dataset B, User 2 is similar to User 1, and according to dataset A, user 1 did not have these trainings yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

One way would be:

```
library(dplyr)

DatasetA %>%
  left_join(DatasetB, by = 'UserID') %>%
  left_join(DatasetA %>% rename(`Recommended trainings` = Trainings), by = c('Similar_Users' = 'UserID')) %>%
  group_by(UserID) %>%
  filter(!`Recommended trainings` %in% Trainings, !is.na(`Recommended trainings`)) %>%
  distinct(`Recommended trainings`)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   UserID [1]
  `Recommended trainings` UserID
  <fct>                    <int>
1 Singing                      1
2 Running                      1
```